# Bootstrap Navbar Toggle Half Working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a bootstrap navbar on this site: http://edmontonconsulting.ca/LawFirm/

On small resolutions, when toggle button clicked, it shows the menu bar, but when clicked again, it does not close the menu.

Comment: try to change in button - data-target=".navbar-collapse" into data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"...

Comment: Already tried this thing, same thing happened.

Comment: There is something wrong with your bootstrap.min.js script... I try to load it from here https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js and instead of your source and it's work like a charm... So change <script src="http://edmontonconsulting.ca/LawFirm/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> **into** <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> and test it...